# I can't make any NN work in Pytorch. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, pytorch, neural-network

I work with data and I have decent skills in python, I know how to work with different models but never before I tried to use Neural Networks.
So I am new to pytorch and I decided to train using online tutorials and videos.

Unfortunately I discovered I really can't make these models work and I get extremely wrong results. This happens regardless of the guide I follow so it's definitely something I am doing wrong.

For example I followed [this step-by-step guide](https://github.com/christianversloot/machine-learning-articles/blob/main/how-to-create-a-neural-network-for-regression-with-pytorch.md) on how to make a NN for regression using the Boston Housing Dataset.

Here is my code that I basically copied from the guide, so there *should* not be any difference.

```py
import torch
from torch import nn
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import pandas as pd

### importing the dataset
boston = pd.read_csv('./housing.csv', header=None, sep='\s+')
boston.columns = [
    'CRIM',
    'ZN',
    'INDUS',
    'CHAS',
    'NOX',
    'RM',
    'AGE',
    'DIS',
    'RAD',
    'TAX',
    'PTRATIO',
    'B',
    'LSTAT',
    'MEDV'
]
xcol = boston.drop(columns=['MEDV']).columns
ycol = ['MEDV']

X = boston[xcol].values
y = boston[ycol].values

### Creating the Torch Dataset
class TorchDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, X, y, scale_data=True):
        if not torch.is_tensor(X) and not torch.is_tensor(y):
            if scale_data:
                X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)
            self.X = torch.from_numpy(X)
            self.y = torch.from_numpy(y)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.X)
    
    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return self.X[i], self.y[i]

### building the MLP
class MLP(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.layers = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(13, 64),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(64, 32),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(32, 1)
            )
        
    def forward(self, x):
        return self.layers(x)

torch.manual_seed(42)

dataset = TorchDataset(X, y)
trainloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=10, shuffle=True, num_workers=0)

mlp = MLP()

loss_function = nn.L1Loss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(mlp.parameters(), lr=0.001)

### training loop
loss_vec = []

for epoch in range(1000):
    epoch_loss = 0

    for i, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):
        inputs, targets = data
        inputs, targets = inputs.float(), targets.float()
        targets = targets.reshape((targets.shape[0], 1))

        ## Zero the gradient
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        
        ## Forward Pass
        outputs = mlp(inputs)

        ## compute loss
        loss = loss_function(outputs, targets)

        ## backward pass
        loss.backward()
        
        ## Optimization
        optimizer.step()
        
        ## Statisitcs
        epoch_loss += loss.item()
    
    loss_vec.append(epoch_loss) 

## Visualizing the Loss curve
import plotly.express as px
px.scatter(loss_vec)

## Checking the R2 score between observed and predicted values    
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

y_pred = mlp(torch.tensor(X, dtype=torch.float)).detach().numpy()


r2_score(y.flatten(), y_pred.flatten())   ##always a big negative number
```

Here is the loss plot
[image]

But the weirdest part is the predicted values

```
pd.DataFrame({
    'Obs':y.flatten(),
    'Pred':y_pred.flatten()
})
```

[image: predicted values]

As you can see my NN is predicting values completely out of the range.

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You train your NN on scaled inputs, as the default value of `scale_data` in the constructor of `TorchDataset` is `True`.

But you do not scale the inputs when you evaluate, as you simply pass a `Tensor` rather than a `DataLoader` from the `Dataset`. This is the reason for the results you're seeing.

Also: This is not the question you asked, but you should separate into train, validation, and test set, rather than testing on the training set.

To predict, use the DataLoader:

```
mlp.eval()
with torch.no_grad():
    y_pred = torch.stack([mlp(batch) for batch, _ in trainloader])
```

Comment: Yes I am aware of the train/test split but for the purpose of this question i decided to disregard it. 
Thanks for pointing the scaling out I never noticed. What's the best practice that you recommend using to get the predicted values out?
Scaling the X and then calling `mlp(scaled_X)` or is there a better approach that makes use directly of the torch dataset?

Comment: edited my answer to include an example - you can in fact scale the tensors as you describe in your comment, but using dataloaders is a good habit to get into, in case your Dataset lazily loads (for bigger datasets)

Comment: @Mirk You can save the scaler as an attribure in your dataset and then use it as you evaluate, something like `X_test = dataset.scaler.transform(X_test)` before inferencing.

Comment: Can you edit the answer and replace `torch.stack` with `torch.cat`? Because if batches are different (last batch is usually partially filled) `stack` won't work.